# AWS ECS Service unable to be created

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I have a deployment that I want to improve, so I made changes to certain variables and created a new VPC for a test version. This is the config:

```yaml
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
    Description: An example CloudFormation template for Fargate.
    Parameters:
      EnvironmentName:
        Type: String
      Certificate:
        Type: String
        # Update with the certificate ARN from Certificate Manager, which must exist in the same region.
        Default: 'arn:aws:acm:xxxxx:xxxxx:certificate/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      FlaskImage:
        Type: String
        # Update with the Docker image. "You can use images in the Docker Hub registry or specify other repositories (repository-url/image:tag)."
        Default: xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxx-xxxxx:105
      NginxImage:
        Type: String
        Default: xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx:10
      ServiceName:
        Type: String
        Default: DemoService
      NginxTask:
        Type: String
        # update with the name of the service
        Default: nginx
      FlaskTask:
        Type: String
        Default: flask
      NginxContainerPort:
        Type: Number
        Default: 80
      FlaskContainerPort:
        Type: Number
        Default: 5000
      LoadBalancerHttpPort:
        Type: Number
        Default: 80
      LoadBalancerHttpsPort:
        Type: Number
        Default: 443
      HealthCheckPath:
        Type: String
        Default: "/api/v1.0/healthcheck"
    #    Default: "/"
      HostedZoneName:
        Type: String
        Default: demo.com
      Subdomain:
        Type: String
        Default: demo
      # for autoscaling
      MinContainers:
        Type: Number
        Default: 2
      # for autoscaling
      MaxContainers:
        Type: Number
        Default: 10
      # target CPU utilization (%)
      AutoScalingTargetValue:
        Type: Number
        Default: 50
      MongodbPort:
        Type: Number
        Default: 27017
      StaticIP:
        Type: String
      PinpointMobileTargetingResource:
        Type: String
        Default: "arn:aws:mobiletargeting:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxx:*"
    Resources:
      #######################################################
      # ECS Cluster
      #######################################################
      Cluster:
        Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
        Properties:
          ClusterName: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, Cluster]]
      TaskDefinition:
        Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
        # Makes sure the log group is created before it is used.
        DependsOn: LogGroup
        Properties:
          # Name of the task definition. Subsequent versions of the task definition are grouped together under this name.
          Family: !Join [ '', [ !Ref ServiceName, TaskDefinition ] ]
          # awsvpc is required for Fargate
          NetworkMode: awsvpc
          RequiresCompatibilities:
            - FARGATE
          Cpu: 2048      
          Memory: 4GB
          ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRole
          TaskRoleArn: !Ref TaskRole
          ContainerDefinitions:
            - Name: !Ref NginxTask
              Image: !Ref NginxImage
              Essential: true
              Memory: 1024
              LinuxParameters:
                InitProcessEnabled: true
              Cpu: 1024
              PortMappings:
                - ContainerPort: !Ref NginxContainerPort
                  Protocol: tcp
              # Send logs to CloudWatch Logs
              LogConfiguration:
                LogDriver: awslogs
                Options:
                  awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
                  awslogs-group: !Ref LogGroup
                  awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs-nginx-demo
            - Name: !Ref FlaskTask
              Image: !Ref FlaskImage
              Essential: true
              Memory: 1024
              LinuxParameters:
                InitProcessEnabled: true
              Cpu: 1024
              PortMappings:
                - ContainerPort: !Ref FlaskContainerPort
                  Protocol: tcp
              # Send logs to CloudWatch Logs
              LogConfiguration:
                LogDriver: awslogs
                Options:
                  awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
                  awslogs-group: !Ref LogGroup
                  awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs-flask-demo
    
      # A role needed by ECS
      ExecutionRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
          RoleName: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, ExecutionRole]]
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Principal:
                  Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
                Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
          ManagedPolicyArns:
            - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy'
      # A role for the containers
      TaskRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
          RoleName: !Join [ '', [ !Ref ServiceName, TaskRole ] ]
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Principal:
                  Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
                Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
          ManagedPolicyArns:
            - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSOpsWorksCloudWatchLogs'
            - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonDMSCloudWatchLogsRole'
          Policies:
            - PolicyName: GroupkashS3Demo
              PolicyDocument:
                Version: "2012-10-17"
                Statement:
                  - Effect: Allow
                    Action:
                      - "s3:PutObject"
                      - "s3:GetObject"
                      - "kms:GetPublicKey"
                      - "kms:Decrypt"
                      - "s3:ListBucket"
                      - "s3:DeleteObject"
                      - "s3:GetBucketLocation"
                      - "s3:PutObjectAcl"
                      - "s3:GetBucketAcl"
                      - "s3:GetBucketPolicy"
                      - "s3:GetObjectAcl"
                      - "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl"
                      - "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl"
                      - "s3:PutBucketAcl"
                      - "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
                      - "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
                      - "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
                    Resource:
                      - "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxx:key/*"
                      - "arn:aws:s3:::demo-backend-images"
                      - "arn:aws:s3:::demo-backend-images/*/*"
                      - "arn:aws:s3:::demo-backend-images/users/*"
                      - "arn:aws:s3:::demo-backend-images/groups/*"
                  - Effect: Allow
                    Action:
                      - "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
                      - "s3:ListBucket"
                      - "s3:HeadBucket"
                    Resource: "*"
            - PolicyName: SMSMessagesDemo
              PolicyDocument:
                Version: "2012-10-17"
                Statement:
                  - Effect: Allow
                    Action:
                      - "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel"
                      - "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel"
                      - "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel"
                      - "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel"
                    Resource: "*"
            - PolicyName: ECSExecuteCommandPolicyDemo
              PolicyDocument:
                Version: "2012-10-17"
                Statement:
                  - Effect: Allow
                    Action: "ecs:ExecuteCommand"
                    Resource: "*"
            - PolicyName: PinpointSMSAccessDemo
              PolicyDocument:
                Version: "2012-10-17"
                Statement:
                  - Effect: Allow
                    Action: "sms-voice:*"
                    Resource: "*"
                  - Effect: Allow
                    Action: "mobiletargeting:*"
                    Resource: !Ref PinpointMobileTargetingResource
      # A role needed for autoscaling
      AutoScalingRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
          RoleName: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, AutoScalingRole]]
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Principal:
                  Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
                Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
          ManagedPolicyArns:
            - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceAutoscaleRole'
      ContainerSecurityGroup:
        Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
        Properties:
          GroupDescription: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, ContainerSecurityGroup]]
          VpcId:
            Fn::ImportValue:
              Fn::Sub: ${EnvironmentName}-DemoVPCID
          SecurityGroupIngress:
            - IpProtocol: tcp
              FromPort: !Ref NginxContainerPort
              ToPort: !Ref NginxContainerPort
              SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref LoadBalancerSecurityGroup
      LoadBalancerSecurityGroup:
        Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
        Properties:
          GroupDescription: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, LoadBalancerSecurityGroup]]
          VpcId:
            Fn::ImportValue:
              Fn::Sub: ${EnvironmentName}-DemoVPCID
          SecurityGroupIngress:
            - IpProtocol: tcp
              FromPort: !Ref LoadBalancerHttpPort
              ToPort: !Ref LoadBalancerHttpPort
              CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
            - IpProtocol: tcp
              FromPort: !Ref LoadBalancerHttpsPort
              ToPort: !Ref LoadBalancerHttpsPort
              CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
            - IpProtocol: tcp
              FromPort: !Ref MongodbPort
              ToPort: !Ref MongodbPort
              CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
    
      Service:
        Type: AWS::ECS::Service
        # This dependency is needed so that the load balancer is setup correctly in time
        DependsOn:
          - ListenerHTTPS
        Properties:
          ServiceName: !Ref ServiceName
          Cluster: !Ref Cluster
          TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
          DeploymentConfiguration:
            MinimumHealthyPercent: 100
            MaximumPercent: 200
          DesiredCount: 2
          # This may need to be adjusted if the container takes a while to start up
          HealthCheckGracePeriodSeconds: 30
          LaunchType: FARGATE
          NetworkConfiguration:
            AwsvpcConfiguration:
              # change to DISABLED if you're using private subnets that have access to a NAT gateway
              AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
              Subnets:
                - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-DemoPUB1-SN
                - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-DemoPUB2-SN
              SecurityGroups:
                - !Ref ContainerSecurityGroup
          LoadBalancers:
            - ContainerName: !Ref NginxTask
              ContainerPort: !Ref NginxContainerPort
              TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
      ###########################################################
      # Application Load balancer
      ###########################################################
    
      LoadBalancer:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
        Properties:
          Type: application
          LoadBalancerAttributes:
            # this is the default, but is specified here in case it needs to be changed
            - Key: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds
              Value: 60
          Name: !Join [ '', [ !Ref ServiceName, LoadBalancer ] ]
          # "internal" is also an option
          Scheme: internet-facing
          IpAddressType: ipv4
          SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref LoadBalancerSecurityGroup
          Subnets:
            - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-DemoPUB1-SN
            - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-DemoPUB2-SN
    
    
      TargetGroup:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
        Properties:
          HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 10
          # will look for a 200 status code by default unless specified otherwise
          HealthCheckPath: !Ref HealthCheckPath
          HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
          UnhealthyThresholdCount: 3
          HealthyThresholdCount: 5
          HealthCheckPort: 80
          HealthCheckProtocol: 'HTTP'
          Name: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, TargetGroup]]
          Port: !Ref NginxContainerPort
          Protocol: HTTP
          TargetGroupAttributes:
            - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
              Value: 60 # default is 300
          TargetType: ip
          VpcId:
            Fn::ImportValue:
              Fn::Sub: ${EnvironmentName}-DemoVPCID
      ListenerHTTPS:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
        Properties:
          DefaultActions:
            - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
              Type: forward
          LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalancer
          Port: !Ref LoadBalancerHttpsPort
          Protocol: HTTPS
          Certificates:
            - CertificateArn: !Ref Certificate
    
    
      DNSRecord:
        Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
        Properties:
          HostedZoneName: !Join [ '', [ !Ref HostedZoneName, . ] ]
          Name: !Join [ '', [ !Ref Subdomain, ., !Ref HostedZoneName, . ] ]
          Type: A
          AliasTarget:
            DNSName: !GetAtt LoadBalancer.DNSName
            HostedZoneId: !GetAtt LoadBalancer.CanonicalHostedZoneID
      LogGroup:
        Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
        Properties:
          LogGroupName: !Join ['', [/ecs/, !Ref ServiceName, TaskDefinition]]
      AutoScalingTarget:
        Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
        Properties:
          MinCapacity: !Ref MinContainers
          MaxCapacity: !Ref MaxContainers
          ResourceId: !Join ['/', [service, !Ref Cluster, !GetAtt Service.Name]]
          ScalableDimension: ecs:service:DesiredCount
          ServiceNamespace: ecs
          # "The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role that allows Application Auto Scaling to modify your scalable target."
          RoleARN: !GetAtt AutoScalingRole.Arn
      AutoScalingPolicy:
        Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
        Properties:
          PolicyName: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, AutoScalingPolicy]]
          PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
          ScalingTargetId: !Ref AutoScalingTarget
          TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration:
            PredefinedMetricSpecification:
              PredefinedMetricType: ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization
            ScaleInCooldown: 10
            ScaleOutCooldown: 10
            # Keep things at or lower than 50% CPU utilization, for example
            TargetValue: !Ref AutoScalingTargetValue
     
    
    Outputs:
      Endpoint:
        Description: Endpoint
        Value: !Join ['', ['https://', !Ref DNSRecord]]
```

My issue now is every resource gets created except the **service resource**. I **suspect permissions** is the issue but the current config here has the same permissions as the production deployment and so I am wondering why this should now be an issue. Perhaps I am missing something that is preventing the **service** from being created.

Comment: Does the service resource show failed in the resource tab of cloudformation?

Comment: It shows failed to create service after a very long wait time

Comment: Do you have public IPs available? Anything useful in Cloudformation (such as a `ResourceInitializationError` with more details in the message)?

Comment: @jordanm this is the final result: The following resource(s) failed to create: [Service]. Rollback requested by user. It took a very long time

Comment: You'll have to dig into the cloudformation and ECS logs to see why it failed.

Comment: @jordanm logs never get created or collected as the ecs service is never created

Comment: The long time indicates the services tried to create but never stabilized. If it were never created, the expectation would be a faster failure